# Spring Boot Application won't start: Attribute 'access' in annotation org.springframework.nativex.hint.TypeHint should be compatible

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-devtools, spring-native

When trying to start my spring boot application I get this stack trace:

```
22:21:06.948 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@707f3c5d
2022-03-01 22:21:07.213  INFO 17588 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.nativex.NativeListener               : AOT mode disabled

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.3)

2022-03-01 22:21:07.253  INFO 17588 --- [  restartedMain] ch.moviepoll.MoviePollApplication        : Starting MoviePollApplication using Java 11.0.14.1 on Desktop-Peter with PID 17588 (C:\Repos\poll\moviepoll\build\classes\java\main started by pebes in C:\Repos\poll\moviepoll)
2022-03-01 22:21:07.253  INFO 17588 --- [  restartedMain] ch.moviepoll.MoviePollApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-03-01 22:21:07.281  INFO 17588 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-03-01 22:21:07.281  INFO 17588 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-03-01 22:21:07.843 ERROR 17588 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attribute 'access' in annotation org.springframework.nativex.hint.TypeHint should be compatible with [Lorg.springframework.nativex.hint.TypeAccess; but a [Ljava.lang.Integer; value was returned
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adaptForAttribute(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:500) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adaptForAttribute(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:475) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adapt(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:426) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.getValue(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:369) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.asMap(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adaptValueForMapOptions(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:315) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.asMap(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:287) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AbstractMergedAnnotation.asAnnotationAttributes(AbstractMergedAnnotation.java:193) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:106) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:81) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.attributesFor(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:285) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:103) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:82) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitionForImportedConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:150) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at ch.moviepoll.MoviePollApplication.main(MoviePollApplication.java:10) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'm not activley using any `TypeHint`, which makes this more confusing.
Using basically what is a standart spring config

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MoviePollApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MoviePollApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.experimental.aot' version '0.11.2'
}

group = 'ch.moviepoll'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/release' }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    // Swagger, OpenAPI
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.5.10'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.named('bootBuildImage') {
    builder = 'paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny'
    environment = ['BP_NATIVE_IMAGE': 'true']
}
```

The only strange thing I did was renaming `movie_poll` to `moviepoll`, but there aren't any more references of `movie_poll` in the whole project. How can I even further investigate this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you already tried this on gradle?

```
./gradlew clean build
```